# share intent through Menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-menu

Hi I am trying to create a share intent, which can be called when menu share button is selected through onOptionsItemSelected. When I press the share button it calls the onOptionsItemSelected but don't give share option. Can you tell what is the error here. I have multiple ways to implement but I want to earn why this is not working.

Here is code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /* Use AppCompatActivity's method getMenuInflater to get a handle on the menu inflater */
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    /* Use the inflater's inflate method to inflate our menu layout to this menu */
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    /* Return true so that the menu is displayed in the Toolbar */
    //MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    //menuItem.setIntent(createShareForecastIntent());

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    String message  = "Yes I am here";


    // TODO (2) Launch the map when the map menu item is clicked
    if( id == R.id.action_share) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        item.setIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(mForecast + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG)
            .getIntent();
    return shareIntent;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you paste, you forget to call-

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

Comment: I have to add in method onOptionsItemSelected after item.setIntent(createShareForecastIntent()) ? Which means after creating intent I am calling it?